# Override DllImport method from parent class

Tags: c#, dll, static, parent-child

I have a `Parent` class, which makes use of a `.dll` from where it imports functions:

```
class Parent
{
    [DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int dllFunction();
}
```

Now I want to make a `Child` class to test the functionality of the `Parent`, without using the methods from the `.dll`. I do not want to use the `.dll` methods, because the `.dll` methods communicate with an external sensor and I want to test the code without input from this sensor. Thus I somehow need to redefine the `.dll` methods such that I can simulate behavior from the sensor:

```
class Child : Parent
{
    public override int dllFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

The current `Child.dllFunction()` method does not work, because the `Parent.dllFunction()` is `static` I think? Is it possible to override the `static` methods of `Parent` in the `Child` class? Or do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend to do it this way instead:

Make the PARENT class function private.  Create a public function that calls it, so its not called directly.

```
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int dllFunction();

public virtual int dllFunctionCaller()
{
    return dllFunction();
}
```

In your CHILD class, overwrite dllFunctionCaller instead.